# The pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

There is some my code. I have a problem.

## include "binarytree.h"

```
int insert2( int num, binarytree** root)
{   
    if ( *root ==  NULL )
    {
        *root = setnode( num, NULL);
        if ( *root == NULL )
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    binarytree *temp , *p;
    temp = *root;
    while ( temp !=  NULL ) 
    {   
        //p = temp;
        if ( num < temp->key )
        {
            temp = temp->left;
            if ( temp == NULL )
                printf( "temp = NULL");
        }
        else if ( num > temp->key)
             temp = temp->right;
    }
    if ( num < temp->key )
        temp->left = setnode( num, temp);
    else temp->right = setnode( num, temp);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why there after some iterations "temp = NULL" is printed , but in while temp != NULL is true!? How???

```
while ( temp !=  NULL ) 
        {   
            //p = temp;
            if ( num < temp->key )
            {
                temp = temp->left;
                if ( temp == NULL )
                    printf( "temp = NULL");
            }
            else if ( num > temp->key)
                 temp = temp->right;
        }
```

Comment: Please improve the title to be less vague. Note also that you change the value of `temp` between the `while` and the `printf`.

Comment: `temp = temp->left;` occurs before you print that it's NULL... that's where it gets set to NULL.

Comment: Before it prints "temp = NULL" you move the current temp node to the left child of the node that was tested when your while loop was performing the comparison.

Comment: You change the value of `temp` right before that line... but the `while()` condition won't be checked again until the next loop iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becuase you change `temp` *within* the while loop.  Remember, a `while` expression is tested *before* every iteration.

We can only assume from your code that `temp->left` is null.